# Android webview not emitting all key events

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple android activity that overrides `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`. All key events trigger correctly.

When I add a webview and use `setOnKeyListener`, only a subset of the key events are triggered compared to the activity `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` handlers.  The webview only triggers certain keys like volume up, volume down, menu, back. It fails to trigger for page up, page down, left, right, up, down, select.

I have tried extending WebView and overriding `onCreateInputConnection` to return a `BaseInputConnection` per some other posts but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because webView is consuming those key events. You can override the keyEvents before they are being consumed by WebView with something like this

```
   webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view: WebView?, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                    // Handle key events here
                    return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perfect! not sure how I missed this but thank you.